# Al cambiar el CSS de unos botones las cajas de texto también toman ese color

Tags: css

He creado un formulario para que los visitantes puedan crear cuentas de usuario. El formulario tiene, además de los correspondientes campos, 2 botones, uno tipo `input`, que es para que una vez que se rellena el formulario, confirmar la creación de usuario. El otro es tipo `button`, que es para cancelar y salir sin crear el usuario.

Código *HTML*:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registro de Usuario</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'sitio.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'metodos.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% if forma.errors %}
<p>{{ forma.errors }}</p>
{% endif %}
<h1>Introduzca sus datos, por favor</h1>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'Registrarse' %}">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forma.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ forma.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forma.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ forma.password }}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>{{ forma.email.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ forma.email }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ forma.first_name.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ forma.first_name }}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>{{ forma.last_name.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ forma.last_name }}</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <input type="submit" value="Registro"/>
         <button onclick="viaje('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')">Retroceder</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Quiero que ambos botones tengan color rosa, para lo cual introduje estos códigos *CSS*:

```
input{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #FFB3FF;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
button{
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 15 px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #FFB3FF;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu css en donde modificas a `input` quita la linea que dice: `background-color: #FFB3FF` eso es lo que le da el color rosa

Comment: @GermanAlzate Si quito background-color, tambien se lo quito al boton "Registro", que es al que le quiero dar ese color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes especificar con precisión el elemento al que quieres aplicar un estilo, por elemento, por *clase* o por identificador.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.azul {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
 
.rojo {
  background-color: red;
}
  
#especial {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<button>Normal</button>
<button class="azul">Azul</button>
<button class="rojo negrita">Rojo</button>
<button class="azul">Otro botón Azul</button>
<button class="rojo">Otro botón Rojo</button>
<button id="especial" class="negrita">Indian Red</button>
```

En tu caso, *deberías* usar una clase para esos botones rosas, porque al poner ese estilo en tu hoja de estilos globales, todos los botones serían rosas, siempre.

Observa como los botones de clase `azul` tienen el mismo estilo, que es diferente del botón estilo `rojo` o `especial`.

Observa también que los estilos pueden combinarse.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar un framework css tipo Bootstrap. Creo que te facilitaría bastante las cosas.

Te dejo un fragmento de cómo quedaría el formulario con Bootstrap:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Tienes más información en la página web: http://getbootstrap.com/